# Passing env variables from docker-compose.yml to the client-side Next.js

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, environment-variables

This is quite silly, but I can't successfully pass my environment vars into my `Next.js` service (run with `docker-compose up`). Anyone can see the bug?

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  ...
  nextjs-client:
    image: nextjs-client
    ports: "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST=192.168.0.9:8080
```

At my `nextjs-client` sourcecode I try to access it with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST`, but it's `undefined`.

Comment: What's actually in that container?  Is the code actually running in the container, or is it a client-side application that runs in the end user's browser (not in Docker and potentially not on the same machine)?

Comment: @DavidMaze as the title suggests, I'm trying to read it at the client-side - at Next.js app. Again - as the env var's name suggests - it's my server's host that the env holds.

Comment: I think you've pointed me in the right direction, it has to do with the SSR/CSR and/or env being passed at runtime/buildtime.

Comment: Is this a static build? If yes, you need to pass the build args instead

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks fine,
Try to exec the container and `printenv` to see if the variable exists.

No need to say, your code should run in the same container, of course.

If it exists, maybe a spelling issue. Check also the process.env declaration vs the docker environment declaration.

Try also to `docker-compose down` to remove the container, might be also a caching issue.

It might be easier to maintain the environment variables with .env file and `docker compose --env-file .env`, but it is not the problem, just a tip.